# How to pass boolean parameters to a restful service?

Tags: wcf, api, rest

What is the best way to pass boolean parameters to a WCF RESTful service?

Using `true`or `false` like this:

`api/resource?hasProperty=true`

or using `0` or `1` like this:

`api/resource?hasProperty=1`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I like the

```
api/resource?hasProperty=true
```

approach because it is more user-friendly.

It tells the API consumer indirectly that it is a boolean parameter. 0 or 1 does not imply that.

Comment: I also like this approach the most because it is more declarative.

Comment: Late addition: you could perhaps make 'yes'/'no' synonyms for 'true'/'false', but I agree, I would never use a numeric with an implied cast to a truth value.

Comment: Using a numeric value does use less data. Or is the impact too little in comparison to the readabilty ?

Comment: @PatrickNijhuis  in the scheme of things, where you are exchanging payloads of few hundred KBs just 3 byte difference is nothing really.

Comment: wouldn't it resolve as "true" on server? then we have to do ugly string comparison

Answer (score 0):

They both are ok! It depends on your underlying logic.

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="api/resource?hasProperty={hasProperty}")]
    bool propertyCheck(bool hasProperty);
```

Or you can use otherwise!

```
OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="api/resource?hasProperty={hasProperty}")]
    bool propertyCheck(int hasProperty);
```

And in its implementation! Just check whether it is "true" or contain "0/1".